# VS Code silent about errors typescript errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have `"strict":true` set in my tsconfig.json file causing `error TS7005: Variable ... implicitly has an 'any' type.` errors when I build my project.

Unfortunately, VS Code only draws three gray on black dots under the 1st char of these variables in the editor, making them very difficult to spot and correct.

How can I get VS Code to draw a red squiggly under those variables to properly reflect they are an error? I'd also like the errors to be listed in the "Problems" tab so I can find and fix them.

**Update**
Here is my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2021"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "outDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "rootDir": "../lib",
    "paths": {
      "src": [
        "../lib"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "../lib"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get both red squiggly lines, and it listed under "Problems", on a new project, for the sample code `const f = (a) => {};`, for the parameter `a`. Steps i took were `yarn init -2`, `yarn add -D typescript`, `yarn tsc --init`, creating a file, writing above same code.

Comment: I replaced my tsconfig w/ `yarn tsc --init` version, no change.